# Assume that $ab \mid (a+b)^2.$ Show that $ab \mid (a-b)^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Assume that $ab \mid (a+b)^2.$ Show that $ab \mid (a-b)^2$.

If $ab \mid (a+b)^²$, then $ab\mid a^2+2ab+b^2 \Longrightarrow ab\mid a^2, ab\mid 2ab$ and $ab\mid b^2$ right?

So since $(a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$ from the assumption we have that $ab \mid a^2$ and $ab \mid b^2$. Now only remains to show that $ab \mid -2ab$ which is clearly true.

Is this valid? I'm not sure about the implication that $ab$ would divide all the terms in $a^2+2ab+b^2$.

Comment: $ab|(a+b)^2$ means that $(a+b)^2=kab$ for some integer $k$. That is $a^2+b^2+2ab=kab\to a^2+b^2=(k-2)ab$ thus $ab|(a^2+b^2)$ and obviously also $ab|(a^2+b^2-2ab$

Comment: Hint: $\, $ if $\ c\equiv d\pmod{\!n}\ $ then $\,c\equiv 0\iff d\equiv 0,\ $ i.e. $\ n\mid c\iff n\mid d\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite: in general, for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a|b+c$ does not imply $a|b$ and $a|c$.
Instead, simply suppose $ab|a^2+2ab+b^2$. That is, $abk=a^2+2ab+b^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The rest sort of follows like the end of your idea, if you subtract $4ab$ from both sides of the equation, then $abk-4ab=a^2-2ab+b^2$, so clearly $ab|(a-b)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $2 \mid 6=3+3$ but $2 \not \mid 3$, so the fact that if $x \mid y +z$ then $x \mid y$ and $x \mid z$ isn't valid (at least in general).
What you just have to use here is the fact that if
$$
x \mid y \text{ and } x \mid z
$$
therefore
$$
x \mid \lambda y + \mu z.
$$
Here, if $ab \mid (a+b)^2$ and since it's obvious that $ab \mid ab$, we have
$$
ab \mid (a+b)^2 -4ab=(a-b)^2.
$$
By the way, if $ab \mid (a+b)^2$, you can show that $a=b$ (see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1223267p6131624)).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said $x \mid (y+z) \nRightarrow (x \mid y) \land (x \mid z)$

What you can say is $ab \mid (a+b)^2 \iff (a+b)^2 = kab, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

This implies $a^2 + b^2 +2ab = kab \implies a^2 + b^2 = (k-2)ab \implies a^2 + b^2 - 2ab = (k-4)ab \implies (a-b)^2 = (k-4)ab \iff ab \mid (a-b)^2$, as required.